# Ember CLI: Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Using a newly-created app in the Ember CLI 0.39, once I added new templates, I started getting this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate data property in object literal not
>   allowed in strict mode

This line, in the concatenated source, is causing the issue:

```
;eval("define(\"app/templates/mytemplate/new\", \n  [\"ember\",\"exports\"],\n  function(__dependency1__, __exports__) {\n    \"use strict\";\n    var Ember = __dependency1__[\"default\"];\n    __exports__[\"default\"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(...)});// #sourceURL=app/templates/mytemplate/new.js);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I came across this because two templates were trying to register with the same name. I'd check that and then that you have `export default` in all the right places. Also, try restarting the server.

Comment: Indeed, it appears that Ember CLI will not allow conflicting templates with the same names: ex. ``users/new``, and ``databases/new``.  Is there a way to get around this?  I want to keep my api consistent, and not have to create "unique" template names...

Comment: You *can* have a template named `users/new` and a template named `databases/new`. I think you might have a problem elsewhere or are somehow registering the templates incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

It might be helpful to post your actual template code.  Most often when I have seen this, it has been due to a duplicate attribute in the template code.  For example, this code in an hbs would cause the same error:

```
{{input value="http://www.facebook.com" type="text" value="http://www.facebook.com"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For others who scoured their templates unable to find duplicate attributes set, mine was a duplicate action in my controller due to a merge.